# Game Center・Google Play Game Serviceを利用したアプリのデータ引き継ぎ機能の一般的な実装方法について

Tags: ios, android

Game Center・Google Play Game Serviceを利用したアプリの
データ引き継ぎ機能の実装について
・iOSからiOS
・AndroidからAndroid
同じOSでデータ引き継ぎを実装したいと考えています。

その機能をGame Center・Google Play Game Serviceのクラウドにデータをセーブする機能を使用して
何かしらのアカウント情報をクラウドに保存する形で実装しようと考えています。
ただこのデータ引き継ぎ機能の実装方法が複数考えられ、他のゲームや一般的な実装方法が
このような方法をとっているかわかりません。

なので同じような機能を実装したことがある方がいらっしゃいましたら
どのような方法で実装されたか教えて頂けますでしょうか。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14206230954

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/183944